# Replace rule using a wildcard

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, placeholder

I have a complicated expression which I want to simplify following a rule. For example, if I want to make the following replacement:

```
A[t] - B*A[t - d1] = Y[t]
```

for any values of `t` and `d1`, for example,

```
A[t - 4] - B*A[t - 4 - d1] = Y[t-4]
```

Using the wildcard underscore notation, I've been able to get a simple version to work,

```
A[t-4] - B*A[-d1 + t-6] /. A[t_] - B*A[d_] ->Y[t]
```

which correctly returns `Y[t-4]`. However, if everything is premultiplied, then I cannot get the right result:

```
(x1*A[t - 4] - x1*B*A[-d1 + t - 4]) /. {A[t_] - B*A[d_] -> Y[t]}
```

which should give `x1*Y[t-4]`. I understand that if I look at the `FullForm` that Mathematica recognizes it as something different, but I need a way around that. I don't think I can easily collect terms as my expressions are something like:

```
(x1*A[t - 4] - x1*B*A[-d1 + t - 4]) + (x1*x2*A[t] - x1*x2*B*A[-d1 + t])
```

and I need a rule which changes that to `x1*Y[t-4] + x1*x2*Y[t]`. I was thinking about using another wildcard before the terms, but this doesn't appear to be working:

```
(x1*A[t - 4] - x1*B*A[-d1 + t - 4]) /. {x_*A[t_] - x*B*A[d_] -> x*Y[t]}
```

Any help or a simple way to make these replacements would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rule = {a_. A[t_] - a_. B*A[d_] :>  a Y[t]};
```

Use it with `ReplaceAll` or `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
(A[t - 4] - B*A[-d1 + t - 4]) /. rule
```

> Y[-4 + t]

```
(x1*A[t - 4] - x1*B*A[-d1 + t - 4]) /. rule
```

> x1 Y[-4 + t]

```
(x1*A[t - 4] - x1*B*A[-d1 + t - 4]) + (x1*x2*A[t] - x1*x2*B*A[-d1 + t]) //. rule
```

> x1 Y[-4 + t] + x1 x2 Y[t]

Comment: This is great, thank you! very clean solution

Comment: @mike_s, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept and welcome to mma.se.